# Strange Artifacts on Astra H Info Display. Scratches?

Tags: opel, vauxhall, saturn, astra

I'm having a problem on my car (2008 Astra H). Since a couple of weeks it's showing some kind of artifacts on the central LCD screen. The screen is not tactile. Touching it doesn't seem to help. I don't know what to try to remove them.

Any ideas?

[image: Astra LCD problem]

Youtube longer video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpA_6gqMk50)

Comment: Finger pressure on the display affects the display because it physically moves the liquid crystal material (which is a continuous film of liquid, not individual pixel-sized cells) and temporarily disrupts whether it is oriented to transmit or block the light. Some of the electronics in the display which orient the liquid crystals at each pixel position have failed - this is not repairable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LCD panel is failing internally and will need replacing with another one. There is no way to repair the panel itself.

Comment: oh, seems that I need to go to my local garage to look for a replacement, as I were afraid of. Thaks anyway!